# Angular material : Tree with nested nodes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to display a working tree using Angular material :https://v7.material.angular.io/components/tree/examples.
It doesn't work and I can't figure why. Please help ^^'

.html

```
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl" class="example-tree">
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle>
    <li class="mat-tree-node">
      <button mat-icon-button disabled class="nav-item"></button>
      {{node.name}}
    </li>
  </mat-tree-node>
  <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild">
    <li>
      <div class="mat-tree-node">
        <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle
                [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.name"
                class="accordion-button">
          <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
            {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
          </mat-icon>
          {{node.name}}
        </button>
      </div>
      <ul [class.example-tree-invisible]="!treeControl.isExpanded(node)">
        <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </mat-nested-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

.ts

```
interface WorkingTreeNode {
  name: string;
  id: string;
  // node: ProjectModel | DatasetModel | RiskAssessmentModel;
  children?: WorkingTreeNode[];
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-working-tree',
  templateUrl: './working-tree.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./working-tree.component.css']
})
export class WorkingTreeComponent implements OnInit{

  treeControl = new NestedTreeControl<WorkingTreeNode>(node => node.children);
  dataSource = new MatTreeNestedDataSource<WorkingTreeNode>();
  workingTree: WorkingTreeNode[] = [];

  userId!: string;

  constructor(private projectService: ProjectService,
    private datasetService: DatasetService,
    private riskAssessmentService: RiskAssessmentService,
    private tokenStorageService: TokenStorageService ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userId = this.tokenStorageService.getUser().id;
    this.buildWorkingTree(this.userId);
    console.log("workingTree", this.workingTree);
    this.dataSource.data = this.workingTree;
    console.log("dataSource", this.dataSource);
  }

  public buildWorkingTree(userId: String): void {
    this.projectService.getUserProjects(userId).subscribe(
      (response: ProjectModel[]) => {
        response.forEach(project => {
          const projectChildren : WorkingTreeNode[] = [];
          this.datasetService.getProjectDatasets(project.id).subscribe(
            (response: DatasetModel[]) => {
              response.forEach(dataset => {
                const datasetChildren : WorkingTreeNode[] = [];
                this.riskAssessmentService.getDatasetRiskAssessments(dataset.id).subscribe(
                  (response: RiskAssessmentModel[]) => {
                    response.forEach(riskAssessment => {
                      datasetChildren.push({name: riskAssessment.name, 
                                            id: riskAssessment.id,
                                            children:[]})
                    })
                  },
                  (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                    alert(error.message);
                  }
                )
                projectChildren.push({name: dataset.name, 
                                      id: dataset.id,
                                      children:datasetChildren})
              })
            },
            (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
              alert(error.message);
            }
          )
          this.workingTree.push({name: project.name, 
                                 id: project.id,
                                 children: projectChildren})
      })
        console.log("getUserProjects HttpResponse workingTRee", this.workingTree);
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert(error.message);
      }
    )
  }

  hasChild = (_: number, node: WorkingTreeNode) => {
    !!node.children && node.children.length > 0;
    console.log("hasAChild", !!node.children && node.children.length > 0)
  }
}
```

I tried to move what is in my onInit in my constructor but makes no difference. I think I do exactly like the example but nothing is displayed and no error appear in my console nor my commande. Thank you for the help you can bring.

Comment: Where are your imports? ```import {NestedTreeControl} from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import {MatTreeNestedDataSource} from '@angular/material/tree';```

Answer (score 0):

The execution of your `buildWorkingTree` is [asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing), which means that your `this.dataSource.data = this.workingTree;` happens before  the `workingTree` actually is populated.

To verify that, you can try adding additional `console.log` next to your `this.workingTree.push` and check the order of the messages being printed out.

You should assign the data to the datasource once it's finished being populated. This might need restructuring all those nested subscriptions into a single observable producing the final result, but that's out of scope of this question - you should probably try to understand the issue of async and create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

ForEach loops are asynchronous, that means next sentence outside the loop is executed before finish the loop. As a fast fix try to use an async/await keywords (I will try to convert your code)
Other solutions is to convert buildWorkingTree methos in a single subscription, as @TotallyNewb says
Here is a possible correction:
`

```
interface WorkingTreeNode {
    name: string;
    id: string;
    // node: ProjectModel | DatasetModel | RiskAssessmentModel;
    children?: WorkingTreeNode[];
  }
  
  @Component({
    selector: 'app-working-tree',
    templateUrl: './working-tree.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./working-tree.component.css']
  })
  export class WorkingTreeComponent implements OnInit{
  
    treeControl = new NestedTreeControl<WorkingTreeNode>(node => node.children);
    dataSource = new MatTreeNestedDataSource<WorkingTreeNode>();
    workingTree: WorkingTreeNode[] = [];
  
    userId!: string;
  
    constructor(private projectService: ProjectService,
      private datasetService: DatasetService,
      private riskAssessmentService: RiskAssessmentService,
      private tokenStorageService: TokenStorageService ) {
  
    }
  
    async ngOnInit() {
      this.userId = this.tokenStorageService.getUser().id;
      await this.buildWorkingTree(this.userId);
      console.log("workingTree", this.workingTree);
      this.dataSource.data = this.workingTree;
      console.log("dataSource", this.dataSource);
    }
  
     async  buildWorkingTree(userId: String): Promise<void>{
      await this.projectService.getUserProjects(userId).subscribe(
        async( response: ProjectModel[]) => {
          await Promise.all(response.map(project => {
            const projectChildren : WorkingTreeNode[] = [];
            this.datasetService.getProjectDatasets(project.id).subscribe(
              async (response: DatasetModel[]) => {
                await Promise.all(response.map(dataset => {
                  const datasetChildren : WorkingTreeNode[] = [];
                  this.riskAssessmentService.getDatasetRiskAssessments(dataset.id).subscribe(
                    async (response: RiskAssessmentModel[]) => {
                      await Promise.all(response.map(riskAssessment => {
                        datasetChildren.push({name: riskAssessment.name, 
                                              id: riskAssessment.id,
                                              children:[]})
                      }));
                    },
                    (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                      alert(error.message);
                    }
                  )
                  projectChildren.push({name: dataset.name, 
                                        id: dataset.id,
                                        children:datasetChildren})
                }))
              },
              (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                alert(error.message);
              }
            )
            this.workingTree.push({name: project.name, 
                                   id: project.id,
                                   children: projectChildren})
        }));
          console.log("getUserProjects HttpResponse workingTRee", this.workingTree);
        },
        (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          alert(error.message);
        }
      )
    }
  
    hasChild = (_: number, node: WorkingTreeNode) => {
      !!node.children && node.children.length > 0;
      console.log("hasAChild", !!node.children && node.children.length > 0)
    }
  }
```

`

Comment: Does this solution works for you ? I copied pasted your code but still nothing is displayed :/ Thank you for the time you spend helping me

Comment: Are you using Developer`s tool on a browser to see if there is an error?
moveover you can put code lines like `console.info('message to show');` before and after loops to see if all is executed in the order you expect